# what means the "-t" in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I'm working with terminal and wondering what means the "-t" tag in commands ?

Comment: Which command in particular?

Comment: Okay well received that was a bad question guys I apologize, you see the tabs I'm new contributor, thanks for your understanding ;).

Comment: All the command you can use are provided by software package you installed on your Ubuntu. If you uninstall some software, you'll no longer be able to use it's commands. They are not provided by that Terminal thing.  Terminal just create a window, open a pty device, redirect input/output of commands to pty device, and display it on the window so you can see it on your screen. So command argument is related to the software providing the command, not related to Terminal.

Comment: Being "a new contributor" does not prevent you from giving it a more thought and investigating a little before posting.

Comment: Roger that captain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost every command has an associated manual page. Suppose the command verb is `ls`, then typing `man ls` at the command line prompt will give you that command's reference page.

The `-t` flag has no specific meaning across all commands. You will need to look at the man page for the particular command to find out what it does.